# React Native - How to generate an APK from EAS that doesn't require a seperate development server

Tags: react-native, expo

Running `npx eas-cli build` creates an APK that I installed on my phone. I do, however, need to start the server from my computer. I would like to have a working APK, that doesn't need this local server.
I modified my EAS slightly according to [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/apk/). Though, unsure if I did right.

My eas.json:

```
{
"cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.3.2"
},
"build": {
    "development": {
        "distribution": "internal",
        "android": {
            "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleDebug"
        },
        "ios": {
            "buildConfiguration": "Debug"
        }
    },
    "preview": {
        "distribution": "internal",
        "android": {
            "buildType": "apk"
        }
    },
    "preview3": {
        "developmentClient": true
    },
    "production": {}
},
"submit": {
    "production": {}
}
}
```

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eas build --profile preview --local
```

--profile preview - gets config from your eas file. You've set "buildType": "apk" there.

--local - means that you'll use your machine for building an app.